# RotateX SVG letters

Tags: jquery, animation, svg

I seek to animate two letters are in SVG format... these are the two visible blue letters if the snippet below is run:

```css
svg {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10% 43% 0
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 890 153" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="logo">
       <path d="M2.7,110.3c-1.4,0-2.7,1.3-2.7,2.7c0,1.1,0.8,1.8,1.1,2c15.1,12.4,30.1,18,48.7,18c24.4,0,41.4-13.9,41.4-33.7
        c0-18.4-12.4-28.6-41.5-34.5C20,58.7,9.5,50.6,9.5,33.8c0-16,14.4-27.4,34.3-27.4c14.3,0,26.2,4.1,37.6,12.9c1.8,1.4,4.6,0.1,4.6-2
        c0-1-0.7-1.8-1.2-2.2C72.5,5.8,60.7,2,44.3,2C21.4,2,4.1,15.9,4.1,34.4c0,19.3,11.9,29.1,42.6,35.3c28.8,5.8,39,13.7,39,30.2
        c0,16.8-14.9,28.7-35.5,28.7c-18.4,0-32.1-5.3-45.8-17.7C4.2,110.7,3.5,110.3,2.7,110.3z" stroke="black" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" data-duration="100" class="letter" style="stroke-dasharray: 653, 655; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-width: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/>     
       <path d="M130.9,3.9c-1.2,0-2.3,1.1-2.3,2.3c0,1.2,1.1,2.3,2.3,2.3h82.3v56.1h-73.8c-1.2,0-2.3,1.1-2.3,2.3c0,1.2,1.1,2.3,2.3,2.3
        h73.8v57.2H130c-1.2,0-2.3,1.1-2.3,2.3c0,1.2,1.1,2.3,2.3,2.3h85.9c1.4,0,2.7-1.3,2.7-2.7V6.6c0-1.4-1.3-2.7-2.7-2.7H130.9z" stroke="black" fill="rgb(98,129,195)" data-duration="100" class="letter letterE1" style="stroke-dasharray: 749, 751; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-width: 0px; color: rgb(98, 129, 195);"/>
       <path d="M456.3,12.7 M377.6,3.9c-1.2,0-2.3,1.1-2.3,2.3c0,1.2,1,2.1,2.3,2.1h87.5l-90.5,117.8c-1,1.4-1.2,1.8-1.2,2.8
        c0,0.9,1.1,2.1,2.5,2.1h94.9c1.2,0,2.3-1.1,2.3-2.3c0-1.2-1-2.1-2.3-2.1h-90.7L470.6,8.8c1-1.4,1.2-1.8,1.2-2.8
        c0-0.9-1.2-2.1-2.5-2.1H377.6z" stroke="black" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" data-duration="100" class="letter" style="stroke-dasharray: 690, 692; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-width: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/>      

       <path d="M256.3,126.8V69.6h73.8c1.2,0,2.3-1.1,2.3-2.3c0-1.2-1.1-2.3-2.3-2.3h-73.8V8.9h82.3c1.2,0,2.3-1.1,2.3-2.3
        c0-1.2-1.1-2.3-2.3-2.3h-85c-1.4,0-2.7,1.3-2.7,2.7v121.8c0,1.4,1.3,2.7,2.7,2.7h85.9c1.2,0,2.3-1.1,2.3-2.3c0-1.2-1.1-2.3-2.3-2.3
        H256.3z" stroke="black" fill="rgb(98,129,195)" data-duration="100" class="letter letterE2" style="stroke-dasharray: 750, 752; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-width: 0px; color: rgb(98, 129, 195);"/>      

     </svg>
```

External version of the above code: http://codepen.io/sylvainusubelli/pen/XmNxQO

The desired effect is to reverse (mirror effect so that the letters face each other) in the same way that, for example with CSS3 transform rotateX and 3D perspective that does not really work on the SVG

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS transforms to perform the animation.  Unfortunately IE doesn't support CSS transforms on SVG elements (yet?).

An alternative would be to use SVG's native SMIL animation (the `<animateTransform>` element etc), but that isn't supported by IE either.  Although you could use the FakeSmile library to add support for that in IE.

The remaining alternative is to use JS animation to adjust the transform on the two letters.  You can do that easily enough yourself, or use one of the many JS animation libraries.

```css
svg {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10% 43% 0
}

svg .letterE1,
svg .letterE2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

svg:hover .letterE1,
svg:hover .letterE2 {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 890 153" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="logo">
 <path d="M2.7,110.3c-1.4,0-2.7,1.3-2.7,2.7c0,1.1,0.8,1.8,1.1,2c15.1,12.4,30.1,18,48.7,18c24.4,0,41.4-13.9,41.4-33.7
  c0-18.4-12.4-28.6-41.5-34.5C20,58.7,9.5,50.6,9.5,33.8c0-16,14.4-27.4,34.3-27.4c14.3,0,26.2,4.1,37.6,12.9c1.8,1.4,4.6,0.1,4.6-2
  c0-1-0.7-1.8-1.2-2.2C72.5,5.8,60.7,2,44.3,2C21.4,2,4.1,15.9,4.1,34.4c0,19.3,11.9,29.1,42.6,35.3c28.8,5.8,39,13.7,39,30.2
  c0,16.8-14.9,28.7-35.5,28.7c-18.4,0-32.1-5.3-45.8-17.7C4.2,110.7,3.5,110.3,2.7,110.3z" stroke="black" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" data-duration="100" class="letter" style="stroke-dasharray: 653, 655; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-width: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/>     

    <path d="M130.9,3.9c-1.2,0-2.3,1.1-2.3,2.3c0,1.2,1.1,2.3,2.3,2.3h82.3v56.1h-73.8c-1.2,0-2.3,1.1-2.3,2.3c0,1.2,1.1,2.3,2.3,2.3
  h73.8v57.2H130c-1.2,0-2.3,1.1-2.3,2.3c0,1.2,1.1,2.3,2.3,2.3h85.9c1.4,0,2.7-1.3,2.7-2.7V6.6c0-1.4-1.3-2.7-2.7-2.7H130.9z" stroke="black" fill="rgb(98,129,195)" data-duration="100" class="letter letterE1" style="stroke-dasharray: 749, 751; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-width: 0px; color: rgb(98, 129, 195);"/>
  
 <path d="M456.3,12.7 M377.6,3.9c-1.2,0-2.3,1.1-2.3,2.3c0,1.2,1,2.1,2.3,2.1h87.5l-90.5,117.8c-1,1.4-1.2,1.8-1.2,2.8
  c0,0.9,1.1,2.1,2.5,2.1h94.9c1.2,0,2.3-1.1,2.3-2.3c0-1.2-1-2.1-2.3-2.1h-90.7L470.6,8.8c1-1.4,1.2-1.8,1.2-2.8
  c0-0.9-1.2-2.1-2.5-2.1H377.6z" stroke="black" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" data-duration="100" class="letter" style="stroke-dasharray: 690, 692; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-width: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/>      

 <path d="M256.3,126.8V69.6h73.8c1.2,0,2.3-1.1,2.3-2.3c0-1.2-1.1-2.3-2.3-2.3h-73.8V8.9h82.3c1.2,0,2.3-1.1,2.3-2.3
  c0-1.2-1.1-2.3-2.3-2.3h-85c-1.4,0-2.7,1.3-2.7,2.7v121.8c0,1.4,1.3,2.7,2.7,2.7h85.9c1.2,0,2.3-1.1,2.3-2.3c0-1.2-1.1-2.3-2.3-2.3
  H256.3z" stroke="black" fill="rgb(98,129,195)" data-duration="100" class="letter letterE2" style="stroke-dasharray: 750, 752; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-width: 0px; color: rgb(98, 129, 195);"/>      
</svg>
```

**Update**

Here's a slightly more complicated version of the above, that works on Firefox.

```css
    svg {
      width: 20%;
      margin: 10% 43% 0
    }

    svg .letterE1,
    svg .letterE2 {
      transform: scaleX(1);
      transition: transform 0.5s;
    }

    svg:hover .letterE1,
    svg:hover .letterE2 {
      transform: scaleX(-1);
      transition: transform 0.5s;
    }
```

```html
    <svg viewBox="0 0 890 153" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="logo">
     <path d="M2.7,110.3c-1.4,0-2.7,1.3-2.7,2.7c0,1.1,0.8,1.8,1.1,2c15.1,12.4,30.1,18,48.7,18c24.4,0,41.4-13.9,41.4-33.7
      c0-18.4-12.4-28.6-41.5-34.5C20,58.7,9.5,50.6,9.5,33.8c0-16,14.4-27.4,34.3-27.4c14.3,0,26.2,4.1,37.6,12.9c1.8,1.4,4.6,0.1,4.6-2
      c0-1-0.7-1.8-1.2-2.2C72.5,5.8,60.7,2,44.3,2C21.4,2,4.1,15.9,4.1,34.4c0,19.3,11.9,29.1,42.6,35.3c28.8,5.8,39,13.7,39,30.2
      c0,16.8-14.9,28.7-35.5,28.7c-18.4,0-32.1-5.3-45.8-17.7C4.2,110.7,3.5,110.3,2.7,110.3z" stroke="black" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" data-duration="100" class="letter" style="stroke-dasharray: 653, 655; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-width: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/>     

        <g transform="translate(173.15 0)">
            <g class="letterE1">
        <path d="M130.9,3.9c-1.2,0-2.3,1.1-2.3,2.3c0,1.2,1.1,2.3,2.3,2.3h82.3v56.1h-73.8c-1.2,0-2.3,1.1-2.3,2.3c0,1.2,1.1,2.3,2.3,2.3
      h73.8v57.2H130c-1.2,0-2.3,1.1-2.3,2.3c0,1.2,1.1,2.3,2.3,2.3h85.9c1.4,0,2.7-1.3,2.7-2.7V6.6c0-1.4-1.3-2.7-2.7-2.7H130.9z" stroke="black" fill="rgb(98,129,195)" data-duration="100" class="letter" style="stroke-dasharray: 749, 751; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-width: 0px; color: rgb(98, 129, 195);"
              transform="translate(-173.15 0)"/>
            </g>
        </g>
      
     <path d="M456.3,12.7 M377.6,3.9c-1.2,0-2.3,1.1-2.3,2.3c0,1.2,1,2.1,2.3,2.1h87.5l-90.5,117.8c-1,1.4-1.2,1.8-1.2,2.8
      c0,0.9,1.1,2.1,2.5,2.1h94.9c1.2,0,2.3-1.1,2.3-2.3c0-1.2-1-2.1-2.3-2.1h-90.7L470.6,8.8c1-1.4,1.2-1.8,1.2-2.8
      c0-0.9-1.2-2.1-2.5-2.1H377.6z" stroke="black" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" data-duration="100" class="letter" style="stroke-dasharray: 690, 692; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-width: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/>      
    <g transform="translate(296.35 0)">
        <g class="letterE2">
     <path id="foo" d="M256.3,126.8V69.6h73.8c1.2,0,2.3-1.1,2.3-2.3c0-1.2-1.1-2.3-2.3-2.3h-73.8V8.9h82.3c1.2,0,2.3-1.1,2.3-2.3
      c0-1.2-1.1-2.3-2.3-2.3h-85c-1.4,0-2.7,1.3-2.7,2.7v121.8c0,1.4,1.3,2.7,2.7,2.7h85.9c1.2,0,2.3-1.1,2.3-2.3c0-1.2-1.1-2.3-2.3-2.3
      H256.3z" stroke="black" fill="rgb(98,129,195)" data-duration="100" class="letter" style="stroke-dasharray: 750, 752; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-width: 0px; color: rgb(98, 129, 195);"
              transform="translate(-296.35 0)"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks you for yours answers !! it working with chrome, but for firefox there are some problems with the transform-origin: 50% 50%

Comment: Sorry. I thought FF had fixed that in the last version.  It must be in v42 that they fixed it.

Comment: I updated the answer with a version that works in FF.

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute **transform**, just adding it to your second and third **path-tag**
More informations [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform)